# lithium framework on shared hosting

Tags: php, shared-hosting, lithium

Don't want to pay for dedicated server for dev work.
I don't want to run a live apache server.

Is it possible to integrate lithium framework into shared hosting account doc-root?

Comment: Why you need a dedicated server for development? Just use your development machine (or use a virtual machine), thus you avoid delay and such.

Comment: needs to be client facing. thus the entire reaosn why i want a live site.

Comment: If it's only one app, try orchestra.io. 1 deployed app is for free, and plays very well with Lithium

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible.
The only requirement is the version of PHP which should be >= 5.3
The [.htaccess](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/blob/master/.htaccess) shipped with the framework is the only thing needed, to get a shared LAMP stack running with Lithium.

Answer (score 2):

If you're meeting the requirements for Lithium (PHP5.3, etc) there's no reason you'd need anything dedicated.

Per http://li3.me/docs/manual/getting-started/requirements.wiki, the only requirement is PHP5.3. Everything else is gravy.

Command line access and stuff like git should come with any self respecting hosting company's offerings, even the bargain basement ones. Some of the optional modules, like MongoDB, can usually be run on the slightly beefier options (i.e. Dreamhost only allows Mong

Check http://nephtaliproject.com/php53hosts/index.php for a list of known shared hosting companies that support PHP 5.3 (or higher)